# Oracle and Asp.net connection

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I use Oracle SQL developer and I made a connection to my database with the system user, after I created a user and made a another connection when I try to run I get the SQL Error:

> "ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
>   specification"

This is my code for insert function:

```
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO SCHEME(CODE,DESC)" & _
    " VALUES (:CODE,:DESC)"

Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("CODE", txtCODE.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("DESC", txtDESC.Text))
```

Comment: The error pretty much tells you...

Comment: It seems you should predix your table name with the name of schema it belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead of your code

```
Dim sql As String = @"INSERT INTO SCHEME(CODE,DESC) VALUES (@CODE,@DESC)"

Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("@CODE", txtCODE.Text))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("@DESC", txtDESC.Text))
```

and also your problem is **invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification**

So please check your table and column name...

That's it..